# What is the best approach to precache static resources?

Tags: caching, service-worker, sw-toolbox, sw-precache

We are trying out `sw-precache` to allow pre-caching of all static resources. We are just thinking which approach to follow for precaching versioned resources which have MD5 fingerprints in their filename.

First solution could be to using `sw-toolbox` and match the URL Pattern and cache them. Whenever you generates file with new fingerprints it automatically get cache and yes, It has a catch to manage the old cache on its own.

Second solution could be `sw-precache` to handle the same and it has advantage to automatic handle old cache. I have tried it but I found sometimes the resources doesn't get updated even on multiple page refresh and even re-opening the browser tab.

Please suggest !

Answer (score 0):

[sw-precache](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache) built with grunt or gulp is the best way to cache static resources.

[sw-toolbox](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-toolbox) is the best way to cache dynamic resources. Example - Caching of Rest API